# Quartz.net configuration and scheduling

Tags: wpf, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a WPF application where the user creates entities in the database. Each entity has some metadata and an interval field. For each entity I want to create a job with the interval provided and store them in the AdoJobStore.
Now since the WPF app will not always be running, I want a create a Windows Service that reads the jobs data from the AdoJobStore and run those jobs.

So essentially there are these 2 tiers. Now I have setup the Quartz tables already in my existing database. My question is:

- How to create/edit/delete jobs from my WPF application
- How to inform my windows service to run the jobs (every time an entity is created in database)

I have read through a lot of blogs but these 2 primary questions are a bit unclear to me. I would really appreciate some example code on how to achieve and may be structure my solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Zero Thread Scheduler to schedule jobs. Example scheduler initialization code:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = tablePrefix;
properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "false";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = connectionString;
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
schedFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
BaseScheduler = schedFactory.GetScheduler();
```

Example scheduling function:

```
    protected ITrigger CreateSimpleTrigger(string tName, string tGroup, IJobDetail jd, DateTime startTimeUtc,
        DateTime? endTimeUtc, int repeatCount, TimeSpan repeatInterval, Dictionary<string, string> dataMap, 
        string description = "")
    {
        if (BaseScheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey(tName, tGroup)) != null) return null;

        var st = TriggerBuilder.Create().
            WithIdentity(tName, tGroup).
            UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(dataMap)).
            StartAt(startTimeUtc).
            EndAt(endTimeUtc).
            WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(repeatInterval).WithRepeatCount(repeatCount)).
            WithDescription(description).
            ForJob(jd).
            Build();               
        return st;
    }
```

Obviously, you'll need to provide all relevant fields in your UI and pass values from those fields into the function. Example screenshot of some of the required fields:

[image: Sample scheduling UI]

Your Windows Service will initialize a Multi Thread Scheduler in OnStart() method in a very similar fashion to the way that Zero Thread Scheduler was initialized above and that Multi Thread Scheduler will monitor all the triggers in your database and start your jobs as specified in those triggers. Quartz.net will do all the heavy lifting in that regard. Once you scheduled your jobs and triggers are in the database all you need to do is initialize that Multi Thread Scheduler, connect it to the database containing triggers and it will keep on firing those jobs and execute your code as long as the service is running.

Comment: Thanks Dean. Sorry was travelling to a different time zone so a little late in replying. The solution makes sense. Just on the job front, from my WPF application I just create the Job details and Trigger Details and call ScheduleJob on the scheduler, which should store the job and trigger detail in my Quartz database tables. And then from the Windows service I get the scheduler and call the Scheduler.Start method to run them jobs. Right?

Comment: Correct, once you initialize your scheduler and call Start() it will monitor your DB and execute any scheduled jobs...

Comment: Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey Dean. Have another possibly very naive question. So I am able to store my jobs in the Sql server database all good from my WPF application. Now I write a windows service that is supposed to Start the scheduler after reading the jobs from the database.  The question is where does the code for the job goes. I mean I need some kind of classs that implements the IJob interface and has an execute method, right?

Comment: You're exactly right, you need a class that implements the IJob and has Execute() method and when the job is triggered it will execute any code you have in that Execute() method...

Comment: Right, so this Job should be ideally in a separate assembly that can be accessed by both the WPF application (for being used by the schedule to create a job of type) and by the windows service so that it can execute the code inside it, Is my understanding correct?